# getUserMedia Got Black Screen

Tags: cordova, html5-video, getusermedia, crosswalk

I try to display video from my phone camera with cordova + crosswalk and can got the video stream from getUserMedia(), but when the stream displayed on html5 video tag, it show black screen.

[image]

I already struggle with this for 2 weeks and not make any progress, please help how to make the video display working properly?

Below are my code to get the video stream and display it

```
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then(function(devices) {

      var sourceID = "";
      var camera = [];
      var currCameraIndex = 0;
      var videoContraint = false;

      devices.forEach(function(info) {
          if (info.kind == "videoinput") {
              camera.push(info.deviceId);
          }
      });

      if(video){
        videoContraint = {
            mandatory: {},
            optional: [{
                sourceId: camera[currCameraIndex]
            }]
        };
      }

      navigator.getUserMedia({
              audio: true,
              video: videoContraint
          },
          function(stream) {

              if(stream.active){

                localVideo = document.getElementById("local-video");
                localVideo.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
                   localVideo.play();
                };

              } else {
                alert('Failed to access your camera or microphone');  
              }

          },
          function(err) {
              alert('Cannot access your camera or microphone:' + err);
          }
      );

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

I use getusermedia to do an Augmented Reality background. I got a black screen exactly like you and was driving me crazy, so maybe I might help with that. I solved it for me just yesterday.

Firstly, I must inform you that I use crosswalk and I found some messages when I ran my project saying 'cordova.deviceready' could not run, or something like that. I updated to the last Cordova (**6.5.0**) and remove and added again the plugins I wanted. I removed and added crosswalk and like a miracle it was fixed and deviceready event was called correctly.

Secondly, I use Onsen Ui because it rocks! And I don't want unnecessary things like Angular and the likes on my app. Just a simpler app for me (I am looking at you, Ionic!!). I start using getusermedia on `ons.ready(function () {..})`

And now, the solution that worked for me. At **platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml** add the following lines:

> ```
> <feature name="Camera">
>     <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher" />
> </feature>
> ```

At **platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml** add the following (they won't get added automatically for some reason):

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
> <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> ```

`android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` might be added but for me the other lines did not. When I added them, all worked just fine!!

### Bonus

Please notice something. If you set **autoplay** in your Html5 video where you show the camera feed, you get a fast responding video and not a laggy one. Did you know that? I did not.

Hope that helps.